# How to print variable from function in main?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in tensorflow and I am searching how to print a variable from a function in the main in Python.
My function is the definition of a convolution which convolute an "image" with weights defined inside the function, this is it:

```
def conv_fn(p_input):
    # Convolutional Layer #1  -------
    weights1 = tf.get_variable("weights1",
        [3, 3, 3, 32], 
        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(
        input=p_input.astype(np.float32),
        filter=weights1,
        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding="VALID")
    conv1_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
    return conv1_relu
```

In the main I want to do the convolution with an image and print it. I read that I have to define a session and eval the variable or feed it. I am lost in this part... This is my main:

```
def main(argv):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    im = [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0,1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0]
    image = np.reshape(im, [-1, 3, 3, 3])
    con = conv_fn(image)
    print("This is image", image)
    print("This is con :", sess.run(con, feed_dict={p_input: image}))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Can you please explain me how I can print:

- the weights from the function conv_fn
- the result of the convolution

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to expose more data to callers, add that data to what you return. You can return a tuple with multiple values; an object with multiple properties; etc.

Comment: BTW, arguments to a function, when split onto different lines from the call itself, should be indented so they're distinguishable from assignments to locals. See the examples of correct indentation in https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation; also relevant are the guidance for spaces around `=` in the "Other Recommendations" section. (There should be spaces around `=` in an _assignment_, but not in a keyword argument)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your work-in-progress around, a good way to do it is to use an object that represents the work done by your function.

```
class Convoluter(object):
    def __init__(self, p_input):
        self.p_input = p_input
        self.weights1 = self.conv1 = self.conv1_relu = None
    def run(self):
        if self.conv1_relu is not None:
            return self.conv1_relu
        self.weights1 = tf.get_variable("weights1",
            [3, 3, 3, 32], 
            initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(
            input=p_input.astype(np.float32),
            filter=self.weights1,
            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID")
        self.conv1_relu = tf.nn.relu(self.conv1)
        return self.conv1_relu

def main(argv):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    im = [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0]
    image = np.reshape(im, [-1, 3, 3, 3])
    con = Convoluter(image)
    print("This is image:", image)
    print("This is con:", sess.run(con.run(), feed_dict={p_input: image}))
    print("Convoluter had weights:", con.weights1)
    print("Convoluter had interim result:", con.conv1)
```